# mahapps.metro.ThemeManager.DetectTheme give me a NullReferenceException

Tags: wpf, nullreferenceexception, mahapps.metro

I have seen the demo of the mahapps.metro and I want to allow changing the theme using a button.

I have a button with a handler and when I click the button it give me a `NullReferenceException`.

```
var theme = ThemeManager.DetectTheme(Application.Current)
```

The theme returned a null value.

I am new in this field. Please help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Take a good, long look at the 'Shared Resources and Themes' section of the [Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx#styling_themes) page on MSDN.

Comment: I don't think @Sheridan comment and the only answer is relevant. MahApps is a WPF metro inspired library, and one of it's functions allows the user to get the current theme that is being used in the application, that is provided by the library itself - The dark theme and the light theme. The problem is that this function is not working on OP case. There is, for instance, a good example [on this page](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/samples/MetroDemo/MainWindow.xaml.cs) Maybe this can help OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the theme as follows:

```
var accent = ThemeManager.DefaultAccents.First(x => x.Name == "Blue");

//dark theme
ThemeManager.ChangeTheme(Application.Current, Accent newAccent, Theme.Dark);

//light theme
ThemeManager.ChangeTheme(Application.Current, Accent newAccent, Theme.Light);
```

Don't miss to import the MahApp resourced in the `App.Resources` section.

Comment: 1 up for mentioning useful hint.